# Using Glew in multiple files

Tags: c++, opengl, freeglut, glew

Somehow I can't get Glew in multiple header files. It is just complaining about Gl is already defined before GLEW.

I have the following file structure in short:

1. Program.h
   includes: `<GL/glew.h>`, `<GL/freeglut.h>` and `"SceneManager.h"`.
2. SceneManager.h
   includes: `"GameObject.h"`
3. GameObject.h
   includes: `<GL/glew.h>`, `<GL/freeglut.h>`.

I do understand that freeglut is in front of glew, but I would like to have the `GL_BGR` extension for example.

> How do I get the `glew.h` in the GameObject as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it a bit different myself right now:

I created a precompiled header with glew and freeglut in it. It looks like this:

```
#ifndef _STDAFX_H_
#define _STDAFX_H_

#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GL/freeglut.h>

#endif
```

Could someone confirm if this is a solid and well know method to do so?

Answer (score 0):

Must be a bug in `glew.h`.

I use GLee instead, which doesn't have this problem.  GLee's test looks like this:

```
#ifndef __glee_h_
#define __glee_h_

#ifdef __gl_h_
    #error gl.h included before glee.h
#endif

#ifdef __glext_h_
    #error glext.h included before glee.h
#endif

#ifdef __wglext_h_
    #error wglext.h included before glee.h
#endif

#ifdef __glxext_h_
    #error glxext.h included before glee.h
#endif

//...
#endif /* !defined(__glee_h_) */
```

So the tests are only done the first time `glee.h` is included.

Apparently glew improperly does the tests outside the header multiple inclusion guard.

I switched from glew to GLee the first time I ran an OpenGL trace (glslDevil, actually) and saw glew calling `glGetString(GL_EXTENSIONS)` hundreds of times at startup.